# Customizing gdb -tui

Tags: debugging, gdb, tui

Over the years, I just can't seem to find a free debugger that suits me.  Normally, I just connect to my university's cluster and use DDT, but I'd like to find something free that I can use locally on my machine.  I've been playing with gdb -tui, but it doesn't have a window to show the other project files or a window for watched variables.  I can't find a way to open up another file in the project in the source window so that I can scan the source code and see where I want to set my breakpoint.  I have to open the other file in vim, find the line number, then set the breakpoint in gdb.  I have switched to doing all my code writing in vim, and that seems to work pretty well for me, but I still haven't found a good all-in-one package for debugging the code after I write it.  Any suggestions from anybody who have a good code development setup would be greatly appreciated.